# Questions about Domain Driven Design (DDD)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have some questions while studying Domain Driven Design.

1. Whose responsibility is it to check for duplicate entities in the logic?
   In my opinion, this logic is clearly a domain-specific concern. Therefore, it should reside in the domain layer. Should I create a DomainService that checks for duplicates and references the Repository from within the service? Or should I create a method in the Repository to check for duplicates? (I have applied the Dependency Inversion Principle to the Repository.)
2. How should I store the private fields of an Entity in the database?
   I understand that for effective encapsulation of an entity, fields should be set as private, and only functions handling domain logic should be exposed. However, to actually store data in the database, I need to access the fields of the Entity. Should I provide getters for this purpose?
3. Can I use domain objects as Input and Output types for ApplicationService?
   Or should I create DTOs to avoid exposing domain objects?
   If DTOs need to be created, should they be created for each service? Or should they be created for each entity?
4. Database design
   I understand that DDD doesn't consider external services, but in reality, services require a database. Typically, should database design be based on aggregates? If it is based on aggregates, should lower-level entities and value objects be separated into tables just like the aggregates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whose responsibility is it to check for duplicate entities in the logic?

In the ideal: the application code is responsible for making information available, the domain model is responsible for performing calculations / applying policy based on that information.

Note that if you are expecting uniqueness because you've got your domain model checking that, you need to ensure that all of the appropriate locks on the data are being held as you perform the calculations for your update.

As a rule, trying to enforce an invariant over a set requires that no other process can modify the set at the same time.  In other words, you need to "lock" the set.  Concerns about implementing the locks at the correct grain may impact your designs of the underlying data model.

Outside of the ideal?  you can find *plenty* of examples where people have chosen to have some domain concerns leak into the application code.

> How should I store the private fields of an Entity in the database?

Most of the literature I've seen pretty well ducks this issue.  Fundamentally, you need some mechanisms in place for getting information out of your domain entity, and mechanisms for reconstituting that entity from the information you retrieved previously.

Once you recognize the necessity, there are lots of ways that you organize the code.  Adding properties so that you can read the information works.  Handles work.  O/RM entities work.  Ultimately, part of what you need to work out is how important it really is to "hide" the fact that persistence is part of your information processing.

> Can I use domain objects as Input and Output types for ApplicationService?

Can you? yes.  Are there tradeoffs?  Very yes.  Especially in the case where your messages cross organizational boundaries, changing the schemas is "expensive".  If you arrange your code such that your messages are tightly coupled to your domain models, then you restrict your ability to change the domain model freely.

> Typically, should database design be based on aggregates?

Which database?

Information is cheap to copy.  The storage solutions that we choose to ensure that we can recover our aggregates after a power outage doesn't have to be the same storage solution we use for answering the questions of the business.

But certainly if you are going to have concurrent processing, then you are going to care a lot about putting logical locks on the changes to your aggregates, and that in turn is going to introduce some constraints on your choice of storage.